# Error loading native librarie libarrow_dataset_jni.dylib in Apache Arrow 7.0.0 Java Dataset API

Tags: java, java-native-interface, apache-arrow

I got this error when I tried to run a simple Java program that uses the Dataset API available in version 7.0.0.

The error occurred when trying to get a NativeMemoryPool using the getDefault() method.

```java
. . .
NativeMemoryPool nativeMemoryPool = NativeMemoryPool.getDefault();
FileSystemDatasetFactory factory = new FileSystemDatasetFactory(
        new RootAllocator(Long.MAX_VALUE), nativeMemoryPool, FileFormat.PARQUET, uri);
. . .
```

By the way, I installed all the binary libraries for my platform using the instructions available at https://arrow.apache.org/install/ and correctly assigned the property `java.library.path` in my Java Program. The fact is that the library `libarrow_dataset_jni.dylib` was not actually installed even though `libarrow_dataset.700.dylib` and several others were installed with the respective symlinks.